# How to manage multiple pageIndicator on run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

How we can show more then 30 pageIndicator in UIPageControl in objective C, its going out from UIPageControl view.

Is there any way to manage that in 10 - 10 blocks/segment at one time.
I am using following code :

```
 - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [(DetailOfferViewController *)viewController index];
    if (index ==0 ) {
        return nil;
    }
    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [(DetailOfferViewController *)viewController index];
    index++;
    if (index == [_data count]) {
        return nil;
    }
     return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
        return [_data count];
//_data count coming with more then 30 numbers 
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {

    return [_rowNumber intValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [Apple's Documentation on `UIPageControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/):

> On iPhone and iPod touch, about 20 page control dots fit on the screen before they are clipped.

Comment: my data count (page control dots) coming more then 30 numbers so that is not fit in side the view